# Issue with FOR cycles, and correlation of IP addresses

Tags: python, firewall, correlation

I'm a newbie to python, trying to create a python3 script which takes an input a CSV formatted like this (it's a firewall ruleset):

```
Source;Destination;Service;Action;Comment
10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/16 192.168.0.0/24 23.2.20.6;10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.3;udp:53 tcp:53;accept;No.10: ID: INC0000000001
```

And correlates the IPs contained within.

I created the following base:

```
import ipaddress
import csv
with open('BE-E2_D1_Source.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        str(row)
        x=';'.join(row)
    for row2 in x:
        y=' '.join(row)
        print (y.split(" "))
```

1st issue: this returns an output which returns 60 times the lines contained within the CSV file. I unable to understand why. Can you help?

2nd issue: I'd really appreciate an input in order to correlate the IP addresses within the source and/or destination.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the data in your file is not separated by comma's, which means you simply loop over all characters in your second loop. See for yourself by printing `row2`.

I believe you are trying to print out something along the lines of `<fieldname>: <data>`, for every row of data in your file.

You don't need the imported modules. The following script works fine.

```
with open('BE-E2_D1_Source.csv', 'r') as f:
    lines = [i.strip() for i in f.readlines()]
    header = lines[0].split(';')
    rows = [i.split(';') for i in lines[1:]]

    for row in rows:
        for idx, field in enumerate(row):
            print(f"{header[idx]}: {field}")
        print()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot probleemkind81. I really appreciate your help. The imported modules are there for the next step, which is the IP address correlation. Do you have any hints also on that?

Comment: What are you trying to correlate the addresses with?

Comment: For example i could have an inventory of IP addresses, where is indicated hostname, IP address, service name, etc... I would like to create something that correlates what is in the firewall rule, to what is in the inventory